# Reusable Performance Monitor Templates

Tags: asp.net, performance, monitoring

I have a Performance Monitor template, under server 2008 R2, that I use for monitoring my IIS server that is saved as an XML file. I have a couple of other servers that I would like to use the same template for. How do I go about loading those settings? Lastly, I'm trying to get a baseline using basic ASP.net counters. What is a good length of time to collect this information, I'm thinking about a month? Any ideas or best practices would be greatly appreciated.